# HBASE_HOME is null and cause “Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries” error

Tags: unix, hadoop, ssh, installation, hbase

I try to run HBase in windows. And got this error
[image: winutils.exe could not locate]
I search and find some answer

a)download winutils and paste it to the bin directory but error still be there.

b)set  HADOOP_HOME , but I don’t know how I must set HADOOP_HOME or HBASE_HOME.

How I can fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve the problem by set an environment variable as HADOOP_HOME and add path of hadoop root as it's path. 
and use hbase-094.27 instead hbase-2.6 and it run without any error.